# How do I create a Javascript var using SQLite data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sqlite, var

I was able to use the examples provided with the Missing Manual series JavaScript edition was very helpful!

**OG.Q.**
I've looked around a bit tried a few different ways, but haven't been able to find a solution.

What I'm trying to do.

1. Save user inputs in a sglite database, accomplished..
2. Retrieve sqlite data as javascript variable, I think this is my problem.
3. Use variable as an ajaxURL to retrieve json, or maybe this is whats wrong.

**Javascript**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var db = openDatabase ("Test", "1.0", "Test", 65535);
    $db.transaction (function (transaction) 
    {
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM scprofiles";
        transaction.executeSql (sql, undefined, 
        function (transaction, result)
        { 
             //I think this is the problem host, id and name are stored in sqlite

            var URL = "http://" + host + "/web/" + id + "/1/" + name + "/";
            var jsonFormat = "?format=json&callback=?";   
            var ajaxURL = URL + jsonFormat;
            $.getJSON(ajaxURL,function(data) {
                $('h1').text(data.displayName);
                $('#stuff').text(data.user.info); 
            });
        }error);
    });
}); //db.transaction

function ok ()
{
}

function error (transaction, err) 
{
    alert ("DB error : " + err.message);
    return false;
} 
}); // end ready
</script>
```

then the html

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="main">
        <h1>JSON Data</h1>
        <div id="stuff"></div>
        <br class="clearLeft">
    </div>
</div>
```

Any advice is much appreciated!

Brent-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale = 1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Read Text</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/jquery/j.m-1.3.2.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/jquery/ld.min.css" />
<script src="inc/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery/scdata-10.js"> </script>
<script src="inc/jquery/j.m-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script>
function saveData() {
  var bnetName = document.getElementById("bnetName").value;
  localStorage["bnetName"] = bnetName;  
  var bnetID = document.getElementById("bnetID").value;
  localStorage["bnetID"] = bnetID;  
  var bnetRegion = document.getElementById("bnetRegion").value;
  localStorage["bnetRegion"] = bnetRegion;  
  location.reload();
}
function loadData() {
  var bnetName = localStorage["bnetName"];  
  var bnetID = localStorage["bnetID"];  
  var bnetRegion = localStorage["bnetRegion"];  
  if (bnetName != null) {
    document.getElementById("bnetName").value = bnetName;
      }
  if (bnetID != null) { 
  document.getElementById("bnetID").value = bnetID;

      }
  if (bnetRegion != null) {
  document.getElementById("bnetRegion").value = bnetRegion;
  }
}
$(document).ready(function () // Call function when page is ready for load..
{
    var URL = "http://" +  localStorage.bnetRegion + "/api/sc2/profile/" + localStorage.bnetID + "/1/" + localStorage.bnetName + "/";
    var jsonFormat = "?format=json&callback=?";   
    var ajaxURL = URL + jsonFormat;
$.getJSON(ajaxURL,function(data) {
$('#results').html( data.displayName + " " + localStorage.bnetRegion + " " + localStorage.bnetID + " <button onclick=' "+ loadData() + " '>Edit</button>" );
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Add StarCraft II Profile</h1>
    <a href="data.html" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" data-ajax="false">Back</a>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
  <fieldset>
    <span> bnet Name </span>
    <input type="text" id="bnetName"><br />
    <span> bnet ID </span>
    <input type="text" id="bnetID"><br />
                <label for="bnetRegion" class="label">Region Host</label>
                <select name="bnetRegion" id="bnetRegion"  data-mini="true" data-inline="true" title="Please choose region host.">
                    <option>--Please select one--</option>
                    <option value="us.battle.net">US</option>
                    <option value="eu.battle.net">EU</option>
                    <option value="kr.battle.net">KR</option>
                    <option value="tw.battle.net">TW</option>
                    <option value="www.battlenet.com.cn">CN</option>
                    <option value="sea.battle.net">SEA</option>
                </select>
  </fieldset>
  <div>
    <button onclick="saveData()">Save</button>
  </div>
        <div id="results">
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```